# Locking JButton to prevent multiple SwingWorkers

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, swingworker

I cant seem to find a way to prevent a SwingWorker from being called twice on a double click.

The issue is that simply setting the JButton to `setEnabled(false)` doesn't prevent someone from double clicking fast enough to run it more than once.

```
startButton.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        makeItSo();
    }
});

private void makeItSo () {
    startButton.setEnabled(false);
    myWorker myW = new myWorker();
    myW.execute(); // Executes allot of work. But errors if this is running more than once.
}
```

Comment: In `makeItSo`, why not set some boolean to indicate that it is running? Then check this boolean before calling the worker execute.

Comment: I have read that doing it that way is very brittle (Which i think means "would not be reliable and could cause issues"). Im seeking to get the "official" way to handle something like this.

Comment: Try using [MouseEvent.getClickCount()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount%28%29).

Comment: @predi That sounds like an excellent idea! I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a `MouseListener` for buttons, you should be using an `ActionListener`

See [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) and [How to Write an Action Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for more details

Comment: Odd, using eclipse, that was what was auto generated. (MouseListener, that is)

Comment: If you're using the Window Editor, you may have chosen to use mouse events, it would be easy to do. Because of the way it works, it should be capable of disabling the button before a second click can occur

Comment: actually, you should use an Action (vs the lower-level ActionListener) - one of its added benefits is to comes with an enabled property that controls the enabled of the button.

Comment: Oh I See! Excellent the ActionListener effectively holds the button until its done calling the code on that thread. (I assume the EDT). Once again @MadProgrammer your awesome. Thanks so much! +∞

Comment: @kleopatra Im not entirely sure what you mean. Are you talking about AbstractAction?

Comment: @TrinaryAtom Take a look at [How to use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use ActionListener instead of MouseListener

why you use  ActionListener, An ActionListener is used to handle the logical click of a button. 
A click happens

```
- when the mouse is pressed then released on a button,
- when the keyboard shortcut of that button is used,
- when the button has the focus and the space bar is pressed,
- when the button is the default button and Enter is pressed,
- when the button's click() method is called programmatically


 A MouseListener only handles low-level mouse events.
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer! This is relevant info to the quest. Thank you!